# Arduino Robot Motor core accidentally overriden

Tags: arduino

Emmm..I am supposedly to plug the USB cord to the top port, but I accidentally plugged it to the bottom port. I'm really new (know nothing) on Arduino. I'm trying to upload `Robot_Motor_Core` from `File/Example/Robot_Motor`, but the program does not even compile. The error message is as follow:

> /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Motor/ArduinoRobotMotorBoard.cpp:
>   In member function 'void RobotMotorBoard::_refreshMotorAdjustment()':
>
> /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Motor/ArduinoRobotMotorBoard.cpp:256:
>   error: 'TRIM' was not declared in this scope

Now I am just panicking because even the `Robot_IR_Array_Test` does not even compile as well. The error message is here:

> Robot_IR_Array_Test.ino: In function 'void loop()':
>
> Robot_IR_Array_Test:22: error: 'class RobotMotorBoard' has no member
>   named 'readIR'

Any advice???? How to set the Arduino robot back to default??

The help doc link is here: http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Robot

Comment: did you actually flash over the bottom board with something. And want to flash it back to what you think it should be?

Comment: @mpflaga I plugged into the bottom board and uploaded a random file. Now the entire robot doesn't even move anymore. I just want to restore the original bottom file.

Answer (score 0):

The above problems appear to be with the IDE and not the robot. A brute force method of making a new directory with a fresh install or unzip of the IDE should fix the errors. And or a reboot or restart of Java.